# Disable react-native-tab-view swipe on area covered by nested FlatList

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-navigation, flatlist, react-native-tab-view

I have a FlatList embedded in every screen of a react-native-tab-view, and I would like to disable the swipe of the react-native-tab-view in the area covered by this FlatList for a better user experience.

When reaching the end of the FlatList, the scroll propagates to the parent react-native-tab-view

[GIF example of the scroll propagating to tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew2Yv.gif)

On Android, the scroll in this area is even sometimes considered as a swipe on the react-native-tab-view, which leads to hard times scrolling the FlatList.

I tried to find a way to catch touch events and stop propagation but I'm not very familiar with PanResponders and touch events captures.

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
    <TabView
      .....
      swipeEnabled={false}
    />
```

Comment: Hi @siicieco!
Unfortunately, I want to enable the swipe on the rest on the screen, but disable it on this small part of the TabView screen